# window.find() returning false even though the text is there

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that can take an exact phrase, and search google for it. Once I click a page, I want it to highlight that phrase on that page. That's where I'm stuck. For me, window.find() keeps returning false in my main.js file. I'm learning Java as I make this for a practice exercise, so please be kind. You might have to explain what some terms mean. Thank you :)

**main.js**

```js
var query = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("query"));
function search(word) {
  query = word.selectionText;
  localStorage.setItem("query", JSON.stringify(query));
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q="' + query + '"' });
};
function findIt() {
  alert("testing: " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("query")) + ", is it on the page? " + window.find(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("query"))))
  window.find(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("query")))
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Google Search",
  contexts: ["selection"],
  onclick: search
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Find Text",
  contexts: ["page"],
  onclick: findIt
});
```

**manifest.json**

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Genie",
  "description": "google searches highllighted text, and then also searches for that text on any page",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/genie.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  }
}
```

**background.html**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

also wasn't sure of the best way to put the code in

Comment: Are you trying to use the unstable [`window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)?

Comment: It's unstable??

Comment: Click the link. It’s non standard and likely going to be removed from browsers.

Comment: 1. Java != JavaScript. Two different animals.

Comment: 2. Please put all your code blocks into one runnable [Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so we can actually see it (not) work.